# Add Access To More Than One Action Method And View Using SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-membership

In my MVC Project I use System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider with `<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>` I restrict all access to views and action methods except `<forms loginUrl="Login/Index" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />`. What if I want to have access to more than one Action method with View. How to add access to more than one Action method and View ?

Web.Config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login/Index" 
        name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add
          name="SqlProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
          applicationName="MyApplication"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          passwordFormat="Hashed" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use the attribute

```
[Authorize]
```

on the controller class and then use the attribute

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

on your action method.
But i'm not sure if it will override the behavior stated under

```
<authorization />
```